# jstree rename node problem

Tags: javascript, jstree

```
bind("rename.jstree", function (event, data) { 
$("#treeDiv").jstree._focused().get_selected().rename(); 
)}
```

Is not working while I am trying to rename a node.

If anyone knows please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
.bind("rename_node.jstree", function (NODE, REF_NODE) {
// Do your operation
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you put styling tags such as `<b> </b>` in the `<li>` item it prevents the rename. Make sure any styling is applied through css if this is the problem, and that should fix it. Also try using `$("#demo1").jstree("rename",node);`